# Laravel Http Facade not reading body params

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-7

I'm sending a request to an API that accepts body params as JSON. But sending a post request it looking like the body params can't be read. How did I know about this is because the API returns the resource instead when the request doesn't have a body.

Has anyone encountered this issue? How can I check that the body params are indeed sent?

TLDR; Laravel HTTP doesn't read body params

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$http = Http::withHeaders([
    'apiID' => 'someAPIId',
    'apiKey' => 'someAPIKey'
]);
$response = $http->post("https://api.com/product/{$product->pid}", [
    'p_supplierprice' => $product->stock_qty
]);
$result = $response->json();

Log::info($result);
```

Comment: if it is not sending body then the api should throw client error have you tries to write all this code in try catch block & thrown then response for error using `$response->throw();` & catch it using `Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException`

Comment: @bhucho it is inside a try catch block, the problem is even if the request fails the api doesnt return an error whatsoever.

Comment: then use debug as true, see guzzle options https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#guzzle-options